# What do I need to do to make the msi inaccessible or not to generate msi in TEMP folder for those people whose conditions are not met?

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield

I have created a single  executable file (.exe) that contains msi file. I have also set some conditions so that the installer will run only when particular conditions are met.

However, the problem is that when I run the exe, it extracts the msi file to a temp directory regardless of whether conditions are met. This means that anyone can just access to our application data if you know enough to extract the data from msi using a free open software like universal extractor.

What do I need to do to make this msi inaccessible or not to generate msi for those people whose conditions are not met?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realize that MSI's are open books. That's the whole point of the technology - to create a standard way of representing installer logic and allow end users (corp IT) to be able to view and transform the behavior.  If you are really uncomfortable with this, then another project type such as InstallScript or another tool such as NSIS may be better for you.   You'll lose all the benefits of Windows Installer though.

If you have some kind of licensing concern, I suggest putting your protection measures in the application not the installer.

InstallShield / Windows Installer doesn't support what you are asking for.